# Don't have relieving letter from previous employer

Tags: india, relieving-letter

I worked in a small company for 2.5 years which was a vendor to company XYZ. I got a chance to offroll to XYZ, resigned with the vendor company and completed its exit formalities with resignation acceptance. I joined XYZ as offrole within 2-3 days.

Now I get an onroll chance with XYZ, but the HR team is asking for the previous 2 relieving letters.

I am working in vendor company for 2.5 years.
I worked through consultancy for 1.5 years.

I have all documents of the consultancy period.
I do not have the relieve letter of the 1st company, but I do have the pay slips and offer letter.

What can I do?

Comment: Shiva, I edited your question for clarity, but am unclear about what 'offroll' and 'onroll' mean. Can you edit their definitions into the question?

Comment: Off roll is a contractor. On roll is a direct employee.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  It does not appear that the OP did not get the relieving letter just that they no longer are in possession of the letter from a previous employer.

Comment: related question: [What are the consequences of not having a relieving letter?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20945/16)

Comment: Strongly agree with Chad. This is a totally different question -- this is asking about how to deal with a request for a relieving letter from several employers ago years in the past, and not about the most recent position which makes it quite different.

Comment: Have you read everything in [What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I don't have a relieving letter from a job, should I exclude those years worked from my total experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80174/if-i-dont-have-a-relieving-letter-from-a-job-should-i-exclude-those-years-work)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can approach them (Vendor company) on their mail id and ask for a copy of your relieving letter. If you have your employee id (it must be in pay slips etc) mention that in subject line and add senior HR management in mail chain. It should work in most cases..

As an alternate option you can tell company XYZ that though you don't have relieving letter from your first employer you do have salary slips and other documents including the experience letter and if they require they can do the background checking using HR mail id of vendor company. In most cases they should be fine with the experience letter and payslips or they can go ahead with email verification which too is common practice now a days. Remember if you have passed all interview rounds and haven't done anything illegal or unethical in past XYZ would be ready to bend 'a bit'.

Once my previous HR manager said to me in a discussion that "80% of our policies are not mandatory for our best 20% employees."

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask the vendor company for another copy of the relieving letter?  I would assume that needing these reissued is not unheard of.  The worst they can say is no.