# How to prove I worked at previous place?

Tags: work-experience, recommendation-letter, cambodia

I am working in a new company now.

At previous company, I was working for a year.It is a small company which has 10 to 15 staffs. I passed the probation after 3 months, but there is no documentation, just an email. I continued working. I leave there after I worked 1 year. I sent the employer a resignation email. We had a short leave interview and He agreed me to leave.

I don't have any letter to prove my previous employment. Now, I want to prove my past workplace and past working period. What can I do?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Cambodia, South East Asia

Comment: Ask your former employer for a letter stating that you worked for them between date 1 and datw 2,

Comment: Paycheck receipts?

Comment: @MisterPositive What kinds of receipts? please specify. I may not have it.

Comment: In the US we get a paystub that goes with our paycheck that show the breakout ( the tax they take out ).  If you deposited your check in a bank, you could get your bank statements.

Comment: Do you mean earning statement? My old workplace pay employee from their HR and issue a letter (earning statement) for each month. It not pay through bank. Is that what you mean, @MisterPositive

Comment: Yep, that should do it.

Comment: Do you not get an experience letter or relieving letter when you leave the job as we get here in India? :)

Comment: No, I don't have it, just email. And I afraid I lost that too. @MaskedMan

Comment: I have written [this India-specific answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/81112/3192), but it might be relevant to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you should have a contract. If not you can use :

- earning sheet provide by your company
- statement from the HR that you worked in this company( if you were a
  decent employee there is no reason they would refuse this)
- recommendation letter from someone of the company
- your bank account receipt with the line where the company gives you a
  salary

You can also provide the email as it is a legal proof.

Comment: OP: "...but there is no documentation, just an email."  LOL, the emails are the documentation.  Besides, their HR will call the Co. HR.

Answer (score 1):

Use your earning statements from the companies HR department.