# Getting a relieving letter from a company that is no longer in business

Tags: india, relieving-letter

I am looking to join a new company ([IDBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDBI_Bank)) and HR is saying it may be a problem if I don't have a relieving letter from my previous employers.

I have relieving letters from the second & third employers, but not from the first since the company closed their operation.

How can I get a relieving letter from a company that is no longer in business?

[For those not understanding what a relieving letter is.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-a-relieving-letter)

Comment: Can you find a public record that the company no longer exists? In the US basic info regarding bankruptcy is available. Do you have to have all the relieving letters for your entire adult life, or does the presence of the 2nd letter remove the need for the first?

Answer (score 3):

If you can proof that the first company went out of business, I can't see why they still need a relieving letter. You can't be an employee of a company that doesn't exists. If I where you I would explain it to them why you only have a relieving letter from the second and third company and if they still require some proof, look for some sort of record that states that the first company went out of business.