# Can I get a relieving letter 2.5 years after leaving my position?

Tags: resignation, india, employer, relieving-letter

I left a known IT firm after approximately 8 months of service to pursue higher education (Aug 2011). At that time, I was in a bond, so serving the notice period did not make much sense. However, I tried to settle everything with the HR. But, I was unable to do so. I informed my manager with an email about my resignation and it was duly acknowledged by him.

Now, after my PGDM for 2 years (not based on my experience) I was selected in an Indian bank. They (third party verification agency hired by the bank) are asking me to submit my relieving letter, but I told them that I was unable to serve my notice period so, I don't have it. Also, I have provided my resignation acceptance mail and manager's number to verify things.

Still they have some forms that require a copy of relieving letter. I don't understand what should I do now?

Is it possible to get a relieving letter now after 2.5 yrs?

Or should I explain everything to the HR in my bank. 
Or maybe try and resolve things with the third party agency only.

Comment: Request the letter.  If you are told it cannot be provided, provide that, if that can't be accepted ask the bank for a solution.

Comment: related question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-a-relieving-letter

Comment: One user from India stated [You can go to labor court if a company refused to provide you a letter](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-a-relieving-letter#comment52427_20946).  I hope someone has some good references to support this and can make that into an answer.

Comment: This relieving letter nonsense just amazes me coming from the US labor market.  Feel bad for people in India who have to deal with it every time they change jobs, good Tamanna.

Comment: @AndrewBartel Wait till this site becomes a hit in Australia. This is one place where you just can't get a job (Any job, in my experience) without a reference ! So if you mess it up with your current employer, good luck finding your next job

Comment: >Or maybe try and resolve things with the third party agency only. Who is the third party here ?

Comment: @happybuddha: The third party here is the agency hired by the recruiting bank for carrying out background checks for the new hire. Perhaps she can resolve things with the third party itself by explaining the complete scenario to them. As the recruiters already know about her resignation and absence of a relieving letter and they still accept the OP's job application, it's just up to the agency now.

Comment: @AndrewBartel - It did me too.  But I had a long discussion with one of our users a year or so ago.  In India it is illegal to have 2 jobs as well... I spent most of my 20's with at least 2 jobs sometimes 3 or 4.

Comment: @happybuddha: What do you mean by "mess it up with your current employer? Does it work the other way? i.e. if the employer messes it up, will they have difficulty finding people?

Comment: @shahkalpesh The supply of talented professionals is so high that people are offering to work for lesser than advertised pay rates. I don't think in the foreseeable future it will ever go the other way.

Comment: The way business is conducted in some places is chilling

Comment: I have never got a relieving letter nor was I ever in a bond after 2 master degrees. What's worse is that I have never heard 'relieving letter' or 'in a bond' before and now I feel this was exactly the subject of conversation those times when I walked in on people who immediately stopped talking.

Comment: I am sorry - what does "I was in a bond, so serving the notice period did not make much sense" mean?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I tried to settle everything with the HR. But, I was unable to do so.

It is hard to answer this question without knowing what the loose ends are and why you were unable to settle everything. Since you were serving a bond, did you owe the company any money before you quit ?

Anyhow, if I were you, I would get in touch with the old employer and ask for a relieving letter. It is indeed possible to get a relieving letter after 2.5 years. I had a few friends from India do the same (not relieving letter but something similar) as a part of their (USA - PR) Green card process. And am told, most companies cooperate for the same.

If there is no response or the company refuses to provide the letter, you can keep a trail of the mail exchanges and submit those to the Bank's HR explaining the situation. You may be able to provide salary slips/bank statements/tax returns proving your employment with the organization in question.

Comment: As you describe anything is possible.  Its just a matter of getting it done.  Its likely the company will refuse to provide the letter.  If thats the case not much can be done.

Comment: @Ramhound - Actually as I understand it there is a labor board that you can take the case to.  That is literally all I know so not really worth an answer to say as such.  I would expect someone who understands the Indian Labor processes could do a great answer to this question though.

Comment: @Chad The reply and messages in the question you asked about Indian relieving letters say that a company can be sued for not issuing a relieving letter. There is no legal tag to this question and neither is it asking for legal alternatives. The question, however, asks 'Is it possible to get a relieving letter now after 2.5 yrs?' Which my answer, more or less succinctly answers. So it would help to understand the context before you downvote