# Is it a problem not to have the Relieving Letter from an earlier employer?

Tags: hiring-process, india, employer, relieving-letter

I am a software professional with around 4 years experience at my present company, and I've worked for 3 companies prior to now. I don't have a relieving letter from the second organisation. Will it create a problem for me in the future if I want to join companies like TCS, Infosys, WIPRO, or Accenture?

Comment: why don't you just ask the second company for the reference letter - which is presumably what a relieving letter is? - and circumnavigate the entire problem?

Comment: @bharal: not quite. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one

Comment: This makes me wonder how did you get your 3rd job without a relieving letter from your 2nd employer. And if you managed to solve that problem back then, why is it an issue now?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience generally the relieving letter of the last job is required. So you are good for a large number of companies. As for the rest don't lose your sleep.