# What is risk of Absconding

Tags: india, termination, relieving-letter

I was on an international assignment for the last 3 months and recently 
arrived back in India (my base location).

During my on-site assignment, my client offered me a job opportunity. Now I have already resigned from my current employer, but my
employer is asking me to pay back everything paid for me during my international assignment (approximately 430,000 Rupees = $6700 US).

I have forwarded that email to my client who's going to be paying
this money, but now they ask me to not pay any amount and offer me
to join directly (at my client place).

What will be the risk if I join the client location directly without having any service disengagement letter (relieving letter)?

What action will they take on me if i'll get abscond?

Comment: What's your actual question here?

Comment: The word "lahk" is not well known outside India. It means one hundred thousand. Does "4.30lahk" mean 430,000? Is that Rupees? If so, that would be about $6700 US at current exchange rates. And I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out just what you're asking.

Comment: So Now Question Is What Will Be Risk If I Will Join My Client Location Directly Without Having Any Service Disengagement Letter With Me(Relieving Letter). Are These People Will Fill Up Any Case Against Me? Please Help Me Out These Situation Thanks For Help And Suggestion

Comment: @Keith Thompson sorry i wasnt aware of currency format well 4.30 lakh means(4300 pound) or 6721.38 USD

Comment: @Phillip Kendall_Apologies well my question is What Will Be Risk If I Will Join My Client Location Directly Without Having Any Service Disengagement Letter With Me(Relieving Letter). Are These People Will Fill Up Any Case Against Me? Please Help Me Out These Situation Thanks For Help And Suggestion

Comment: @Amit I have edited your comment answers into the question (don't use all these capitals please) but you still need to improve it, because it's not clear who *they* are in the 3rd paragraph. Please [edit] and also add the country that you new employer is located.

Comment: @Amit Two more notes: (1) legal question are off-topic on this site and (2) have you seen this http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one.

Comment: "*4.30 lakh means(4300 pound) or 6721.38 USD*" -- So 1 Indian Rupee is 0.01 British Pound. (I'm not sure why you're referring to pounds if you're from India.) And *please* don't capitalize every word of every sentence; it just makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check your employment contract for any terms relating to this sort of situation? Sure, they can sue you for the payment in India and probably never affect you while you're overseas, but just know that if you ever return and try to find a job there, you *might* have a negative reputation with employers in your industry.

If I were in your situation, and I did all the work required by the company while overseas, and my contract did not have any clause regarding the repayment, I would do the ethical and fair thing and return the money equivalent to a return ticket at the time of purchase.

Comment: He also may face consequences upon returning if he does not have his relieving letter.