# Do I need relieving letters from all my past employers or just the most recent one?

Tags: new-job, job-change, india

I work in Ahmedabad, Gujarat India. If I were to change jobs, would it be necessary to provide reliving letters from all my past employers or is the letter from my last employer sufficient?

For example say, if I worked with company A,B and C in the past and am currently working at company D. If I'm changing jobs to start with company X, is it necessary to show my relieving letters from A, B, C and D or am I only require to show the last one which I will get from company D?

Comment: Assuming your question is about **relieving letters** as used in India, that is answered here: ["Do you need to keep all of them or just the most recent letter?"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/20946/25739)

Comment: yes i mean relieving letter only.

Comment: Hello again Vishwas, I have edited your question to improve the language and clarify what you're asking. Since your question seems adequately covered by the linked question I've also voted to close this as a duplicate. Note that the linked answer only offers a general guideline: whether a company will require all letters or just your most recent is specific to that company so we can't say for sure.

Comment: okay @Lilienthal, no prblem. and thanks to  all for the replies

Comment: No problem Vishwas, it's a good first question to ask here and the linked question wasn't very searchable so it's good that this question is now here to redirect people to that answer.