# HR is not replying after selected and submitted EAF for 2 months

Tags: human-resources, software, relieving-letter, consultants

HR from a giant company is not replying after selected and submitted EAF for 3 months.1 month ago when I called them they told them on processing.I asked them how much time required for processing. Now when I called them after 3 months they told them that the manager has not selected you for the particular project.Now should I wait for when they will get next project? I have also resigned from my previous Company as they want the Relieving Letter from the current company while submitting EAF Onboarding. They haven't send me the Offer Letter till now.

Comment: Please clarify (1) What is EAF? (2) _they told them that the manager has not selected you for the particular project_ Who are _them_?

Comment: The one thing that is clear in this question is resignation from previous employer without having received an offer letter from a new employer. That is not a good plan.

Comment: Guess: Employment Application Form.

Comment: *"Actually, **no."*** The OP in this case is stuck between *Indian* employment law, in which "it is illegal for a person to have more than one job at a time" (http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one), .and the *very(!)* short-term viewpoints of Western Capitalists."

Comment: To clarify:  "although the Indian Government is, by regulations such as these, understandably trying to be protective of Its Citizens," *every one of 'Its Citizens'* should very-soberly have a deep drink of this thought:  **"Why, *exactly,* is The USA so gosh-darned interested in 'me, way over here' in the first place, in preference to *its own* citizens, 'right there at home?"** Be very careful not to let yourself be caught-up in an international situation that you (and, your family) do not *fully* understand. (After all, they don't call 'em **"Non(!)-** Immigrant Visas" for nothing!)

Answer (score 2):

You've been rejected, move on and find another job elsewhere.

Comment: what are the possible reasons that they reject me...after this long process. I can't understand how to recover after waiting for 5 months. If they rejected me why don't they inform me within 3 months.After login in my profile in company's website there is nowhere written that I have rejected.

Answer (score 1):

EAF => Employment Application Form, I presume?

Anyway, you don't have this job. Go for the next one at a different company.