# Employer not accepting my resignation

Tags: management, human-resources, company-culture, india, relieving-letter

I joined a company just 3 months ago. My marriage got arranged suddenly and I will be moving abroad with my fiance. When I notified HR of my resignation, they behaved very rude and said they will not accept my resignation. Moreover, they will only grant me 5 days off for my wedding. If the company does not accept my resignation, I will not receive a relieving/experience letter.

What actions can I take to force my company to accept my resignation and receive my relieving letter?

Comment: Hello Madhu Smita, welcome to the workplace. Your question is quite hard to understand. What exactly is your goal here? If your company doesn't let you take leave for your wedding, and you don't plan to work after marriage anyway, why not just leave the job?

Comment: +1 @MaskedMan  I don't know what country you're in, but I highly doubt the company can actually *force you* to continue working for them.  Don't ask them to leave, *tell them you're leaving* and then leave, regardless of protests.

Comment: I joined my Company 3 months ago.All of sudden my marriage got fixed and I have to move abroad with my husband.When I spoke to HR Manager ,My company where I work is not giving me relieving. They are asking me to stay with the company.

Comment: @Madhu Smita So just go abroad with your husband. What is the problem? They can ask whatever they want, you just don't show up to work. What can they do? Chase you down in a foreign country? I don't think you are thinking this through properly.

Comment: A location tag might also help.  Based on the usage of "I will not relieve you" and "...is not giving me relieving", sounds like this is India and you are concerned about not receiving your relieving letter.  If that is the case, there are many possible answers you can find here by searching for "relieving letter"

Comment: Kindly inform HR that slavery is illegal and you have a legal right to put in your notice to terminate your contract within the legal limit. Inform them that not accepting the notice is a breach of contract and thuis allows you to TERMINATE IMMEDIATELY WITH DUE CAUSE DUE TO BREACH OF CONTRACT. Period.

Comment: @TomTom this sounds like it's in India. Things are a lot different there (I used to work there). I still don't exactly understand relieving letters, but I think they're kind of like letters of reference, not getting one from a former employer is kind of like getting black listed. But I don't think there's any legal protection for employees seeking these letters (that's why they exist, as a sort of cartel among employers to keep employees in-line).

Comment: It seems that you are going to move far away. If you are moving abroad and staying abroad, then nobody cares about your relieving letter. If you applied for a job in the UK for example, nobody would care one bit about getting a relieving letter from India, and it would actually be one of the situations where you are allowed to moan about your last employer. On a personal note, I would highly recommend that you don't get married to a man who thinks he has the right to tell you whether to have a job or not.

Comment: To extend Glen Pierce's comment: employment law in India is very different then in the US or Europe. When moving to a new job employees are supposed to provide a [relieving letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one) from their previous employer verifying that they are leaving their job. If you don't have the letter you may not be allowed to start your new job. Unscrupulous employers can punish employees by refusing to provide the letter.

Comment: Is omitting mention of this job an option to not explain a lack of relieving letter? Assuming the time between this job and the previous one isn't too long, 3 months + interim time doesn't seem too questionable for a gap.

Answer (score 5):

**Good news**: relieving letters exist only in India, so if you are moving abroad, nobody will ever ask you for one again.  If you have payslips to prove you worked there, and if possible a personal reference or two (managers, colleagues etc), you will be just fine.

Comment: I just want to add one more important thing. Leave a paper train to cover your ass. Just send an E-Mail from your work E-Mail address to your boss/manager stating your resignation and cc your person E-Mail address. Just call it preparation for worse case. If company decide to sue you, or anything, you have proof that you resigned.

Answer (score 0):

The employee (you) has the right to terminate the employment contract via a resignation. This does not need to be accepted by the organisation as you are informing them of your intention to leave the company. You are however required to serve your notice period. If for some reason you are unable to do so you need to discuss this with your manager and negotiate if possible an alternate end date which both parties should agree to if it is less than the required contractual notice period.