# Management Not Responding To My Resignation

Tags: management, resignation, india, notice-period, health

I have been working in a Software company and I have a bond there for 2 years. I have already served for 1 year 8 months. Unfortunately I'm now having some health issues and wanted to discontinue my work. I have talked to my reporting manager in person about this and drafted him a resignation email on Nov, 1st.

It's been 19 days since I resigned and he is not responding to me. I have talked to him and also sent a followup email. He said that he will get back to me in a week or 10 days and still no response.

I have talked to the HR team as well, and they are asking me to wait for my managers decision. I have drafted a followup again 3 days back and still don't received any response.

Since I have to serve a notice period of 2 months according to the company policy, I said to them that I will serve that period and then leave by Dec, 31st 2018. Also I have attached the required medical reports. He is responding to other work related emails but not my resignation.

Can some one suggest me what to do now?

I'm from Hyderabad, India. Also my bond does not include anything about the scenarios in which an employee can leave the company.

Comment: As long he got the notice, you don't have to wait for their approval. I also don't get why you added the medical reports? That's something between you and your doctor. (answer may be depending on where you live). Maybe check with a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. He asked me to provide the required medical proofs. So, I have added my reports. So, do you mean that I don't need to wait for their response anymore and leave the company after completion of my notice period

Comment: what are the terms of the bond? what are the consequences of quitting before two years? Also adding your  country would help get good answers.

Comment: What is your locale? Do you need a Relieving Letter or similar?

Comment: Please put a country tag in as this could impact the correct course of action.

Comment: this can only be India

Answer (score 19):

## Review your Employment Contract and continue with your plans of resignation.

Your notice of resignation does not require your manager's approval, and so long as you are acting within the employment contract, there is nothing they can do about you leaving. You do not have to follow HR's advice about 'waiting' so long as you stick to the terms set out in the employment contract and I would strongly recommend against following your HR's advice.

Remember the Golden Rule of dealing with HR: **HR is not your friend. It exists solely to look after the company's interests**

Comment: " there is nothing they can do about you leaving." He works in India, where an employer can definitely create problems for a leaving employee. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one

Answer (score 1):

OP has updated the location as India; this advice doesn't apply there.

Leaving it in case it has value to a future reader who is in the US.

---

> I have a bond there for 2 years

By "a bond" do you mean that you entered into a contract for employment that lasts two years?
If so, I'm not sure why you would need a response from your boss.
`No, that isn't what he meant.`

Having said that, makes sure *that the notice you have given* is a **valid notice**.

Check your contract about valid ways to give notice - if it doesn't specify a way, and the contract is in writen form (in person / not emailed) then you *may* have to give it to the same way they gave it to you (they could choose to regard the email as not a valid notice). Given no specific form of notice in the contract (email/FAX/telegraph/etc.) you have to respond in the same form that the offer was given in.
You don't mention a country, so this may not be relevant - but it generally is correct for contract law in the US. Note that I'm not a lawyer, and most companies wouldn't refuse to pay because you didn't notfy them the right way... but most companies would have a boss that responds to a resignation; not doing so is weird to me).

Even if I'm correct in my assumptions, it may not be 'contract law'. It could be covered under 'employment law' and it is it, even within the US each state has specifics that add/override agreements or parts of them related to employment.

Get an employment lawyer's opinion if it isn't *very clear* how to give notice in your contract.

Comment: Given name and phrasing OP is likely in India where you are legally required to your employer to serve to the end of your notice period.  US law is likely not applicable.

Comment: Just to add, according to the law in India, a bond is only enforceable if the employer has invested a similar amount to the amount of the bond. Usually, Indian companies keep these bonds absurdly high to scare employees, which will never hold in a court of law as the employer can never be able to prove they invested such a high amount (usually it is an amount of 100,000 rupees or more). Source: I resigned from such a company myself.

Answer (score 0):

Once when an employee submit his resignation, his notice period starts from that day, and now company don't have any control on you, yeah it is good if they will revert you back, but if they don't then don't worry no one can hold you, as you have health issue and you also submit your health papers as you mention, so on 31st December 2018, throw a fairwell mail you your colleagues. If management or company try to hold you and you are not interested in it then you can take the legal help also, but i hope  management will not hold you back as they can't.