# Do I need to share with new company that I did a short stint at a new company?

Tags: india, employees

I was waiting for a final interview / offer letter from X company in India. Meanwhile I joined another company Y (also in India) because the offer was going to expire before company X could give me a final offer.

One month after joining Y company, I got final offer from X company which was much better than Y company. I resigned and got relieving letter from Y company.

I did not inform X company about joining/leaving Y company. Do I need to tell company Y about my stint at company X? Are there any risks if I choose to disclose?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Indian regulations. In the USA, you are not required to disclose this short employment unless your new employer does extensively background checking such as for a security clearance.

Comment: @jcmack Regulations and customary employment practices in India are very different from the US.

Comment: Whats a relieving letter?

Comment: Can the downvoted please explain what is wrong or needs to be improved in this post?; @solarflare: and explanation of a relieving letter https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one

Comment: I downvoted it because it is off topic on a few levels: it is asking for company/region specific advice, it is asking for what could be seen as legal advice and it is asking for a specific choice in what to do.  It is also not relevant to anyone living outside certain geographic locations.  These make it off topic for the Workplace SE.  Why do you ask @sharur you didn't post the question..?

Comment: @solarflare: I ask because questions can only be improved or fixed if the their problems are known, **because people downvoting without explaining what is wrong (or upvoting a comment that explains what you feel is wrong) with the question annoys me**, because the whole stack community can improve questions, not just the OP (and also, because VSK is flagged as a new contributor).

Comment: @VSK https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sharur I can see you spent a lot of time trying to argue with me (unnecessarily).  If a question is specific to one locale the population of that locale is irrelevant.  That was a weird flex by saying India has more people than Europe, not sure how it contributes to the argument. Another thing, this forum is community moderated so if one person downvotes others can upvote, it doesn't mean anything. Please don't get upset over every downvote you see, you will have a rough time on this forum.  We wouldn't want you to end up getting upset over every downvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86959/discussion-between-solarflare-and-sharur).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need for you to do so.

Also, I think the mistake in the first place was to actually believe that the offer's expiration date is written in stone.

The reality is that almost no company is going to disregard you if you need one week extra to provide an answer, the idea of providing an "expiration date" for an offer is simply a way to pressure you into accepting the offer, which is totally fine, as the job of the company is to attract talent, but it is your job to make sure you get the best offer.

Think about it, do you think that after a long interview process, when the IT company finally (finally!!) gets the right candidate, then they are going to ditch him/her just because the candidate says that needs a bit of extra time?

So anyway, going back to the original question, no need to do that at all, it is not really relevant anyway, so do not overthink it.