# Can an employer apply to an MNC without a relieving letter from the previous job?

Tags: india, relieving-letter

I've worked for 7 months in a company which had a bond of 2 years, working on an overtime and not being paid for it as well as the management being bad, I decided to resign.

On putting down the resignation,the company denied to accept it stating the bond period is not complete.And thus I dont have my relieving letter.

Is it advisable to apply to an MNC as a fresher, or can I state my work experience as i have the pay slips?

Comment: Did the contract state overtime would be paid? if it did and they did not pay it, then it could possibly be argued that they have already broken the contract... You need to see a lawyer...

Comment: @SolarMike Employment bonds are already illegal in India. So, employer had broken the law, let alone the contract. :)

Comment: @AnishSheela Any references on this? AFAIK employment bonds are not always enforceable, but certainly not illegal.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev See my answer below. My friend had successfully used this to get out from an employer and got relevant documents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one)

Answer (score 2):

In India, [bonded labor is illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonded_Labor_System_(Abolition)_Act,_1976). Just threaten them [quoting the rule](https://labour.gov.in/sites/default/files/TheBondedLabourSystem(Abolition)Act1976.pdf) and you will make a complaint to labor officer, as they are breaking the law. If they are not budging, consult a lawyer or labor officer.

Also, talk to the recruiter of the MNC and check if they are OK with this. In most cases, they will approve and take an alternate documentation (Salary slip).

Its not advisable to join as a fresher, as its difficult to get and essentially lying, which is a ground for termination for most employees. You have to explain what you were doing in 7 months.

Also, prepare a good answer on why you are leaving the old company within an year. It will definitely come in the inter

Comment: So, send another resignation letter with the copy of the material sent to the Labour Officer - should be fine... But don't expect much in their recommendation letter...

Comment: Personally, I would leave out the letter, unless they ask for it. New employer can take a hint that they can also get the same treatment from you.

Comment: @SolarMike Also, its a reliving letter. Just mentions that the person is employed from this date to this date and they left on their on accord.