# How to make sure that relieving process is smooth for me?

Tags: resignation, india, notice-period

I resigned from my job 3 weeks back. The resignation was a verbal one and upon asking my manager, if any written communication is needed? My manager asked me not to put up any mail as management wanted to give me a counter offer.

I also communicated my new employer date of joining keeping in my 2 months notice period. I also informed my management about the same. I was promised that there would not be any problem in my relieving if I do not accept the counteroffer.

When I say management it means my direct manager and her manager(very senior guy, country head) as well.

After 3 weeks of this discussion, I did not receive any counter offer so I finally emailed the HR department about my resignation. HR is now saying 2 months notice starts from the date of the email. HR also said that they would discuss the matter with management. Also, my manager is now unhappy that I have involved HR in this.

My manager still says there won't be any issue in my relieving but is not giving the same in email.

I have now started feeling that I have made a mistake not writing the email on the first day itself. What can I do now to make sure there is a smooth and timely relieving process.

UPDATE: There was no issue in the relieving process and everything went smooth.

Comment: Where do you live? This sounds like something that might depend on legislation and local laws. As well as your contract.

Comment: I am staying in India.

Comment: Does your contract say anything about whether resignations have to be in writing?

Comment: I did not read the contract but relied upon the information provided by manager probably a mistake. I will read the contract.

Answer (score 7):

> What can I now do to make sure there is smooth and timely relieving process.

At this point, the only thing you can do is look through your contract and see if there is a provision that allows for a verbal resignation.  If there is, show it to your HR department and ask your manager to confirm the date you resigned.

In the future, you need to make sure that any important information is communicated in writing/electronic format.  This way, there is a record of exactly what was communicated and the exact time.

Comment: And I can do nothing if there is no such clause in my contract? Should I inform my new employer about what just happened? Or should I trust my manager and do nothing?

Comment: Isn't "trusting your manager" what got you into this situation?

Comment: Yes it did. It feels like I trapped myself into this situation. This is a learning experience for me.

Comment: What can your current employer do to you if you stick to the 2-month notice from the time you verbally resigned?  I wouldn't necessarily cause problems with your new employers for the sake of placating the old manager who is trying to get you in trouble..

Comment: @GeorgeM Maybe delay issuing a [relieving letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20945/19325)

Comment: Mmm that would be a problem indeed.  Can the OP involve their direct manager's senior boss, the one who was involved from the start, as a witness?  If they are equally dishonest about it, there would be nothing to do but ask the new employer for a 3-week delay :-(

Comment: That is the plan exactly.