# Feeling cheated by my organization due to incorrect details in relieving letter

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, employer-relations, politics, relieving-letter

**Summary**: I worked as Software Developer, and now found a new job. My previous job wrote relieving letter stating that I was Associate Software Developer (lower rank). I will ask manager for a correct letter. I've cleared all the interview rounds at the new job, but afraid they will reduce my salary, or fire me thinking I lied.

---

I was working in my current organization as a Software Developer from last 2 years 6 months. When I joined this company, my profile was **Software Trainee**. But after 3 months, I was confirmed here and was given the profile of **Associate Software Developer**. The promotions in my organization happens in April. I was given a good amount of hike in both 1st and 2nd promotion and during my second promotion, the General Manager of my organization told me that now I am promoted as a **Software Developer**. I asked him that this was not written on appraisal letter.

He said that they don't have a policy of writing this on appraisal letters. I said OK and changed my profile from **Associate Software Developer** to **Software Developer** on LinkedIn and resume. Till my 2nd year, General Manager was performing the role of HR also as my company is miser by nature.

Now, about a month ago, I got an offer for **Associate Consultant** position from another organization and I resigned from my current company. Today was my last day here. In my relieving letter, I saw that the profile mentioned was **Associate Software Developer**. I told the recently hired HR person that this profile isn't correct as the correct profile is **Software Developer** which our manager told me during my 2nd increment. She asked me to give a written proof which I didn't have and at that time, the manager had left the office.

Now, I didn't accept the relieving letter and I have decided to go tomorrow to talk to the manager to tell the HR to write my correct profile. I was counted as among one of the best performers of my organization and I didn't believe that they would do this with me.

I am quite tensed that if my cunning, politician manager wouldn't write my correct profile in the relieving letter then it could have adverse effect on my career especially in the new organization (which is giving me 80% hike) as they would say that I was lying about my profile.

Although I've cleared all the interview rounds conducted by them but still I'm unsure of how they would react and whether it can have adverse impact on my image as well as my career. I'm afraid as if I could lose the new job or they would reduce my CTC also because they would think as I'm lying but I wasn't.

Can someone please advise what can be done in these kind of situations?

Comment: I've added TLDR section on top, trying to distill the issue. Please fee free to modify as you see fit

Comment: location would help here

Comment: @DarkCygnus It's India guaranteed.

Comment: @AriKari yes, it's likely. In India the use of Relieving letters is highly common I've seen

Comment: @DarkCygnus yes, my organization is in India

Comment: I'd never heard of a relieving letter till today. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one

Answer (score 4):

You are blowing up the situation. You shouldn't have mentioned about this to the HR in the new company. Most of the times, these designations really do not matter, esp in your years of experience range.

You can always contact your previous company to get the designation corrected. And, be prepareded for the worst. 
If it is not corrected, then at your new company, do not talk about it until asked. If they ask, tell them that there was a mistake in your understanding. Do not explain much or do not drag that conversation.

Do not repeat this mistake at your next interview or company.

And this wont have any adverse effect on your career. Don't stop interviewing. There are many companies in india. You are bound to get a good job. Be patient.

Comment: The manager of my previous organization has made the correction of the designation in my relieving letter.

Comment: I'd agree with the mentioning and the non-difference between Associate Software Developer and Software Developer, but just for anyone else finding this, you might want to be explicit about that in your answer: If they messed up Junior Software Developer with Software Developer that would be a major mistake and indeed have some impact.

Comment: @TheHungryCoder Congratulations. You did get lucky.