# Can I give the resignation at month end without serving notice period?

Tags: resignation, notice-period

I am willing to give resignation at the last day of month and not serving the notice period, will it be accepted?
I have 2 months notice period and willing to resign immediately.

Comment: Where in the world are you? What does your contract say?

Comment: "will it be accepted?" How could we possibly know that? Why are you trying to resign immediately anyway? There is a lot that you're not telling us.

Comment: You should have probably gave at least a weeks notice of resignation, this is the nominal period over here in the UK. I see two options, they ask you to work a reasonable notice period or they accept your resignation and terminate you with immediate effect. They would possible hold any money owing or just not pay you for the notice period. It would really help us if we knew where you are?

Comment: In most of the countries the company has no way to force you to go to work. But if you fail to honour the contract, the company might be able to take legal action against you forcing you to pay indemnities.

Comment: @SJuan76 Or in India, not give you the infamous [relieving letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one) in which case you won't (legally) be able to get another job.

Comment: make sure you are still in probation. If yes. Then you will not have to serve the full notice period (in my company (india) for probation employees notice is 1Week. For permanent employees the notice period is 1month) FYI

Comment: For a helpful answer please provide more information, such as country tags, if possible contract information, laws that might apply or if you are still in probation. Without knowing your situation it is nearly impossible to give a helpful answer. Please edit your question accordingly. Thank you and welcome to The Workplace

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If your contract has a two month notice period, then you have to give them two months notice.

They *might* agree to let you go immediately without serving the period, and it's often in the company's interest to do so (because they're probably not going to get much useful work out of you for if you're there against your will, and it gives you more chance to steal confidential information or try and take clients with you or stuff like that). But that's entirely at their discretion.

If you just say "I quit, and I'm not coming back" then can't *force* you to come into work. But depending on where you are, they might be able to withhold your pay for your last month, or may be able to sue you for breach of contract (although it's probably not worth their time to do so). Don't expect a good reference though.