# What should I do if there is 3-4 weeks delay for previous company relieving letter?

Tags: human-resources, india, background-check, relieving-letter

I recently joined XYZ company after resigning from ABC company, and I have submitted documents for Background verification for XYZ. But, I didn't receive previous company's relieving letter. Now my HR of XYZ noticed it and is asking me to submit **as early as possible**.

I came to know that previous company's relieving letter may take **3-4 weeks** to get generated.  Meanwhile, I submitted my **resignation acceptance email** of ABC company to my current HR.
But, there is still **no response** from my current HR.

What should I do if there is 3-4 weeks delay for previous company's relieving letter?

Comment: How do you came to know about this delay? Did ABC told you that via email or similar?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I came to know from resigned employees from ABC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one)

Comment: Although the linked question is related (relieving letters) and recommended reading, it does not answer the question OP asked at all... @gnat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now my HR of XYZ noticed it and asking me to submit as early as possible. [...] What should I do if there is 3-4 weeks delay for previous company relieving letter?

If there is a 3-4 weeks delay, then that would be "as early as possible" given the circumstances and internal ABC's processes.

What I suggest is that you **inform XYZ's HR about this 3-4 week time frame**, so they are aware of that and everything is clear for both parts.

Comment: Do you think that this **3-4 week time frame** is **too late** to submit docs for BGV?

Comment: @TimJack IMHO it does seem like a longer-than-I-would-expect time for a document, although I don't know what is the average time for a relieving letter to be generated... however, what I think is irrelevant as that 3-4week frame is a fact, and I can't change their processes and times, and besides, those times surely depend on the size of company ABC, their efficiency, etc...